# Convert WAV into MP3 using FFMPG with the carrier_wave gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

Inside my "wave_uploader.rb" script I have the following code:

```
class PictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  include CarrierWave::MimeTypes

  version :wav do
    process :convert_to_mp3

    def convert_to_mp3
      temp_path = Tempfile.new([File.basename(current_path), '.mp3']).path

      `ffmpeg -t 15 -i #{current_path} -acodec libmp3lame -f mp3 #{temp_path}`

      File.unlink(current_path)
      FileUtils.mv(temp_path, current_path)
    end

    def full_filename(for_file)
      super.chomp(File.extname(super)) + '.mp3'
    end
  end
```

I am trying to convert the WAV file into a 20 second MP3 file and delete the WAV file once it is converted. The code above runs but I can't find the converted MP3 file so I am guessing it did not work correctly.

At the end of wave_uploader.rb I have code that returns the unique name once it is processed but I commented out the code out thinking the code below was causing the WAV file not to be converted to an MP3.

```
# def filename
#   "#{secure_token}.#{file.extension}" if original_filename.present?
# end

# def secure_token
#   var = :"@#{mounted_as}_secure_token"
#   model.instance_variable_get(var) or model.instance_variable_set(var, SecureRandom.uuid)
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated on how to get this working right.

Comment: Your code sample is not syntactically correct. You're missing an `end`. When submitting code it's essential it is acceptable to Ruby.

Comment: Thank you, fixed the end part, but still not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing I see is:

```
`ffmpeg -t 15 -i #{current_path} -acodec libmp3lame -f mp3 #{temp_path}`
```

If `ffmpeg` is not in your path then the OS won't be able to find it, and will return an error, however, because you're using backticks, the OS can't return a string from STDERR, which is where the error would be displayed. Backticks only return STDOUT.

To debug this try this from the command-line:

```
which ffmpeg
```

If `ffmpeg` is found, instead of:

```
`ffmpeg -t 15 -i #{current_path} -acodec libmp3lame -f mp3 #{temp_path}`
```

Try:

```
puts `which ffmpeg`
```

and see what is output.

I suspect it's not in your path, so you'll have to locate where it is and provide the full path to where it is on disk.

Also, it's better to move the original file, move the new file to the original file's name, then delete the original or leave it as a ".bak" file. That way the original is kept until all the code has processed:

```
  FileUtils.mv(current_path, current_path + '.bak')
  FileUtils.mv(temp_path, current_path)
  File.unlink(current_path + '.bak') # <-- optional
```

Comment: Okay, I had to install avconv on the server. Also, i changed  `temp_path = Tempfile.new([File.basename(current_path), '.mp3']).path` to `temp_path = "#{current_path}#{Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')}"` because avconv was asking if I wanted to overwrite the original file. I am having one issue now. File.unlink is removing the tmp/ file but carrierwave still stores the original uploaded file in its directory along with the newly created mp3 file.

Comment: That would be a separate question.

Comment: Thanks, I made a separate question.